# Difference between UIWebView(deprecated) and webkit View in swift

Tags: ios, uiwebview, webkit

I am starting learn webview in ios swift but i am unable to understand the difference between uiwebview and webview kit. recommend some article or documentation so that i can make it clear.

Comment: Simple - UIWebView is obsolete. Use WKWebView. What other information are you looking for that you don't see in the reference documentation for the two classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIWebView` is deprecated and should not be used in apps and `WKWebView` is the replacement for that .

If you compare it performance wise, `WKWebView` outperforms `UIWebView` in case of memory consumption as `UIWebView` consumes a lot of memory to load the same webpage and `WKWebView` on the other hand does not consume that much. You can easily create a demo app and see for yourself

As per Apple Documentation

> In apps that run in iOS 8 and later, use the WKWebView class instead
>   of using UIWebView

So, to sum it up, if you want to load a webpage inside your app, you can use `WKWebView`

Also, not really what you asked for, but you should also look inside `SFSafariViewController` if you want some Safari related features such as Reader, AutoFill, Fraudulent Website Detection, and content blocking.

You can find more about [SFSafariViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller)